# Cannot find ArrayList object

Tags: java, arraylist

The NumberTile class models a number tile which is an arrayList of 4 integers, the `TileGame` class inserts a tile into the board, and a test class to start the game. A hand is an arraylist of 5 `NumberTiles`, but when I compile this, every time I reference to an ArrayList of `NumberTile` in `TileGame`, it cannot find the symbol NumberTile.

Do I need to create a package so it would recognize it? My instructor provided most of those statements and I cannot change them. I did not type the other methods because I do not think they are necessary.

Also, the line `TileGame game = new TileGame();` says cannot find symbol. What would be the right way to initialize it?

I need any help I can get. Thank you.

**Class `TileGame`:**

```
public class TileGame 
{ 
    //provided by instructor
private ArrayList<NumberTile> board ;

  // Creates an empty board
   public TileGame() 
   {
     //do not modify this method
       board = new ArrayList<NumberTile>();
   }

  // Accessor for the board
   public ArrayList<NumberTile> getBoard() 
   {
    // Do not modify this method
       return board ;
   }

  // Creates and returns a hand of 5 random number tiles
   public ArrayList<NumberTile> getHand() 
    {
       ArrayList<NumberTile> hand = new ArrayList<NumberTile>() ;

       for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++)
       {
        hand.add(a, new NumberTile());
    }

       return hand;
   }

   // If the current tile fits in the board (without rotating) then
   // return the index i of a tile in the board so that the current tile 
   // fits before ti for i = 0..k-1, or return k if the current tile fits
   // after the last tile.   If the tile does not fit, return -1
   public int getIndexForFit(NumberTile currentTile) 
   {
       NumberTile firstTile = board.get(0);
       NumberTile lastTile = board.get(board.size() - 1);

       if(firstTile.getLeft() == currentTile.getRight())
       {
           return 0;
       }
       else if (lastTile.getRight() == currentTile.getLeft())
       {
           return board.size() - 1;
       }
       else 
       {   
        return -1 ;
       }
   }

   // Call the method getIndexForFit to see whether a tile can be inserted
   // into the board. In this method the tile can be rotated. If the tile
   // can be inserted, return true.  If the tile does not fit after 
   // rotating (at most 3 times), return false.
   public boolean canInsertTile(NumberTile currentTile) 
   {
       //call get index for fit
       int canInsert = getIndexForFit(currentTile);
       boolean canInsertOrNot = false;;
       //if true, modify index
       if(canInsert == -1)
       {
           //rotate
           for (int rotations = 0; rotations < 3; rotations++)
           {
              currentTile.rotate();
              int didRotationWork = getIndexForFit(currentTile);

              if (didRotationWork == -1)
              {
                  continue;
              }

              else if (didRotationWork != -1)
              {
                  canInsertOrNot = true;
              }

           }

           return false;
       }

          else if(canInsert != -1)
          {
              return true;
          }
       return canInsertOrNot;

   }

   // Make a move. I.e. if a tile in the hand fits on the board
   // then remove it from the hand and place it in the board. If no tile
   // from the hand fits, then add another tile to the hand
   public void makeMove(ArrayList<NumberTile> hand) 
   {
       boolean fits;

       for (int x = 0; x < hand.size(); x++)
       {
           //call caninterserttile
           fits = canInsertTile(hand.get(x));

           if(fits)
           {
               int index = getIndexForFit(hand.get(x));
               board.add(index, hand.get(x));
               hand.remove(x);
               break;
           }
           else
           {
               hand.add(hand.size() -1, new NumberTile());
           }

       }
    }

   public String toString() 
   {
       // Do not modify this method
       return board.toString() ;  // ArrayList as a String
   }
 } // end of TileGame class
```

**Class `NumberTile`:**

```
public class NumberTile 
{
  public ArrayList<Integer> tile = new ArrayList<>();

// Constructs a NumberTile object using 4 random integers in the 
// range 1 to 9
 public NumberTile() 
  {
     Random generator = new Random() ;

    for (int a = 0; a < 4; a++)
    { 
        int random = generator.nextInt(9);
        tile.add(a, random);
    }

  }
// Rotate the tile 90 degrees
public void rotate() 
{
    int temp = tile.get(0);
    tile.set(0, tile.get(1));
    tile.set(1, tile.get(3));
    tile.set(3, tile.get(2));
    tile.set(2, temp);
}

public int getLeft() 
{
      // Do not modify this method
    return tile.get(0) ;
}

public int getRight() 
{
    // Do not modify this method
    return tile.get(2) ;
}

public String toString() 
{
    String out = "";

        out += "   "+tile.get(0)+"   ";
        out += tile.get(1) + "   " + tile.get(2);
        out += "  "+tile.get(3)+"   ";

    return out;
 }

} // end of NumberTile class
```

**Class `TileGameTester`:**

```
public class TileGameTester {

public static void main(String[] args){
    TileGame game = new TileGame();
    boolean winner = false;

    //get two hands
    ArrayList<NumberTile> hand1 = game.getHand();
    ArrayList<NumberTile> hand2 = game.getHand();

    //create an empty board
    System.out.println(game.getBoard());

    do{
        //make moves
        game.makeMove(hand1);
        game.makeMove(hand2);

        //check if they won
        if (hand1.isEmpty() || hand2.isEmpty())
        {
            winner = true;
        }

    }while(!winner);

    hand1.toString();
    hand2.toString();

    if (hand1.isEmpty() && hand2.isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.println("It is a tie!");
        }
        else if (hand1.isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.println("Player 1 won!");
        }
        else if (hand2.isEmpty())
            System.out.println("Player 2 won!");


   }
}
```

Comment: The declarations for the hands are probably wrong, but  I do not know which other way to create them since there are no Hand classes. I was told I have to use NumberTile arrayLists but I do not really how that makes sense.

Comment: Are they in the same folder?

Comment: Yes they are in the same folder

Comment: Including the TileGameTester? If they are all in the same folder/package, you should not need to import them. And if it is different, that would explain the cannot find symbol. Also it appears you are missing a bracket at the bottom of the TileGameTester. Not sure if that is just in this or in your actual code as well.

Comment: TileGameTester is in the same folder as well. My professor said I do not need to create a package, but that it might be useful. Would it fix the cannot find symbol errors?

Comment: Not necessarily, but you can try it. Can you update your post to include all of your source code please? The error might be something missing that would only be visible by seeing all of the code.

Comment: Your class `TileGame` has no method `getHand()`. At least not with the code you provided.

Comment: I will post all the methods

Comment: it's terribly formatted but I posted all the code

Comment: Why not fix formatting? Your IDE should do that for you with a shortcut.

Comment: It is neat in the IDE but when I paste it here I have to space everything again

Comment: Btw. you may also want to read **[how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).** For example: _"Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."_

Comment: It appears you are still missing a bracket at the bottom of your TileGameTester class. Is this in your code as well? Also do you have any imports in any of these classes?

Comment: I am not missing the bracket in the code. I have the imports for arrayList and for Random. that's it. Also I did not create a package.

Comment: What IDE are you using? It compiled fine for me, but running it ended with a runtime crash.

Comment: BlueJ which one did you use

Comment: The best of all, (just kidding its probably near the bottom), DoctorJava. You might just need to restart your IDE or individually compile everything.

Comment: I had DrJava but it stopped working

Comment: What is the runtime error it show when you run it?

Comment: `IndexOutOfBounds` that appears to be caused by the tester class. Have you tried restarting the IDE or individually compiling the files?

Comment: Yes I did. I ran it in NetBeans and it says that, IndexOutOfBounds, I think it is because the arrayLists does not contain anything

Comment: Wonderful, so your original question has been answered?

Comment: No, because it still cannot find the object In netbeans.

Comment: I stopped using BlueJ

Comment: I must have misunderstood your question. Was it a pre-compile error or a runtime error?

Comment: In netbeans it is a compile error but in BlueJ it is runtime. I do not know which one to trust

Comment: It compiles in BluejJ but says that the line NumberTile firstTile = board.get(0); returns a IndexOutOfBoundsException

Answer (score 1):

Though it is incomplete so i am not sure if you are adding data to the arraylist or not but if you are getting Symbol not found .

I am also not able to see any import statements . Did you import the objects

eg TileGameTester should have import -> `import com.something.TileGame` and `import com.something.NumberTile`

also check if you have import statement in TileGame  and common imports like arraylist

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to insert "import java.util.Random;" and "import java.util.ArrayList;" between your package declaration (if you have one) and the class declaration in the files where these are used.

Comment: I have them in the files they are used

Comment: I do not have a package declaration

Comment: Where are the methods getHand() and makeMove() defined?

Comment: In the TileGame class

Answer (score 0):

You can import TileGame class to TileGameTester class that might solve your issue.

Comment: Do I need to create a package to do this? This is prob a stupid question but I am new to programming